# Probability of being dealt at least 1 ace, 1 king, and 1 jack

Tags: probability

Following the example of [this already answered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636289/probability-of-at-least-one-king-and-at-least-one-ace-when-5-cards-are-lifted-fr) I tried to extend the logic to another card and I'm not getting the correct answers.

Following the above example of being dealt 5 cards ${52 \choose 5}$ represents all possibilities, ${48 \choose 5}$ represents the all hands without a King (or ace/jack) and ${40 \choose 5}$ represents the values we have already done (since hands without an ace may also not contain a jack).

The equation I used was:

$$\frac{{52 \choose 5} - 3{48 \choose 5} + {40 \choose 5}}{{52 \choose 5}}$$

And I get a negative number. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to add back all of the ways of not drawing a pair of the interesting cards (there are three such combinations), but then you’ve overcounted again and have to subtract a term for all three cards. You do well to look up inclusion/exclusion as someone suggested in the other question.

Answer (score 1):

You have **three** kinds of cards.

Designate the events of: $\bar A$ "no aces", $\bar J$ "no jacks", $\bar K$ "no kings"; which are complements of "at least one ...".

Use the *Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion* (and the rule of complements).

$\def\P{\mathop{\sf P}}\begin{align}\P((\bar A\cup \bar J\cup \bar K)^\complement) &= {1 -\P(\bar A)-\P(\bar J)-\P(\bar K)+\P(\bar A\cap\bar J)+\P(\bar A\cap\bar K)+\P(\bar J\cap\bar K)-\P(\bar A\cap\bar J\cap\bar K)}\\[2ex] & =\dfrac{\dbinom{52}5-3\dbinom{48}{5}+3\dbinom{44}{5}-\dbinom{40}{5}}{\dbinom{52}{5}}\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

The term you are subtracting should contain ${40 \choose 5}$. As we have to remove cases with no king, no jack, no ace. Total 12 cards.

So term becomes,

$$=\frac{\binom{52}5-3\binom{48}{5}+3\binom{44}{5}-\binom{40}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$